# Cannot Perform Two-way Binding in an Input Element Dynamically

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following object in my typescript class:

```
export class XComponent {
    fields: [{ }];

    constructor() {
        this.fields = [
        {
            id: 'Id1',
            name: 'Field 1',
            value: 'lorem'
        },
        {
            id: 'Id2',
            name: 'Field 2',
            value: 'ipsum'
        },
        {
            id: 'Id3',
            name: 'Field 3',
            value: 'dolor'
        },];
    }
}
```

When I try to bind the value dynamically in an input element it binds the last value which is **dolor**.

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; index as i">
    <label>{{ field.name }}</label> <!-- This one is rendered correctly. -->
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fields[i].value" />
</div>
```

### Result

```
    Label: Field 1
    Input: dolor

    Label: Field 2
    Input: dolor

    Label: Field 3
    Input: dolor
```

Comment: Also if you use two way databinding, as the bottom answers mentioned keep in mind that two way databinding is pretty rxpensive, through the fact that you have to listen bidirectional. It's by far more efficient to use input and output events separately and provide them from a smart component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass the index anymore. You are looping thought an array of objects with the *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields;">
    <label>{{ field.name }}</label> <!-- This one is rendered correctly. -->
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field.value" />
</div>
```

Here's a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fre6m5

Answer (score 1):

just use `[(ngModel)]="field.value"`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field.value" />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5bkmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)